# How to Pass data from express middleware directly back to client JWT and Express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, middleware

I am currently stuck trying to implement a refresh token with express middleware, react and JWT. The problem I am having is I need to pass the refreshed token back to the client from the middleware function. I have tried using res.locals.variableName and also res.set, but once the middleware function is finished and next() is called, I am responding with res.json in my route, which I think is overwriting anything I set in the response from the middleware. How can I return this refresh token to client side while still being able to call next()?

```
app.all('*',  function (req, res, next) {

  const headerToken = req.headers.token;
  const refreshToken = req.headers.refreshtoken;
  const isVerifiedPath = verifyPaths(unauthorizedPaths, currentPath);


  if (isVerifiedPath) {
    next()
  }
  else {
    jwt.verify(headerToken, process.env.KEY, async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        if (err.expiredAt) { // expired web token
          jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.KEY, async (err, data) => {
            if (data) {
              const User = require('./models/User');
              const user = await User.query().findById(data.user.id);
              const token = jwt.sign({ user }, process.env.KEY, { expiresIn: 5 });
              req.user = user;
              res.locals.varName = token; // I would like this to be accessible from the response my api returns
              next();
            }
          })
        }
        else {
          return res.status(401).json({ err: 401 });
        }
      }
      else {
        req.user = data.user;
        next();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: How do you expect `res.locals.varName` to be accessed? How does your route use `res.locals`, what is getting overwritten there?

Comment: Immediately after res.set or res.locals.varName is set, if I console.log(res) it is there. Same within the route called after next(). But, in the route called after next() I am returning res.json(random stuff) and I want the response to include the refreshToken and be accessible from client side. The problem is that it isn't there once it's returned to client side. I'm assuming it is getting overwritten by the res.json(), would that be the case? @Bergi

Comment: How would you expect it to be sent to the client? As a header? As part of the body? `res.locals` is usually used with a view engine, not raw json responses.

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware of that. But Yes I would like to be part of the body or header without including it from the route called after next(). I have tons of routes, so Ideally I would like it to be attached to the response object from the middleware function if that's possible. @Bergi

Comment: If you want to send it as a header, just send the header from the middleware. To send it as part of the body, the route(s) need to cooperate.

Comment: I've already tried, res.set('x-token', token) but by the time I log the response on client side the headers are not there. @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to pass the token through headers like this. I wasn't able to view the token client side because I was not exposing the header (line 2).

```
res.set('x-token', token);
res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-token');
```